# Are SalesForce apps always installed on an environment?

Tags: salesforce

...as opposed to just a user? To put it another way, if a user installs an app, will it always be added to the environment such that all other users can use it (assuming they've been given permission)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: yes. Installed applications (AppExchange, or other) are always installed on a full Salesforce environment. However, User Profiles, Permission Sets, or Licenses may restrict access to the application.

If the installed application is licensed, and the User has a license, and the User's Profile has access to the necessary objects, tabs, code, etc., they will be able to use the installed app. By limiting permissions, an installed app can be completely hidden from Users.

Comment: Cool, thanks! And do the users get their own data or is it shared? Can everyone with access to the same app see everyone else's object instances for that app?

Comment: Access to data is based on permissions, as well. Each User has a Role in a Hierarchy (like an org chart). Based on that Role, permissions to access data can be granted to specific Users based on their position, manager, etc. If more control over data access is needed, there are Sharing Rules as well, and these can be implemented within the Salesforce interface or with Apex code. All that can get really complicated fast, and it's not my specialty.

Comment: Granting everyone access to see everyone else's records is easy, though, by the way. (It's controlled by the View All / Modify All Profile permission for a given object).